# Insert selected value into get parameter array

Tags: php, forms

I do have a simple html form with select fields. the first field ask for the number of persons. The other fields ask for the age of each person:

```
<form action="#">
  <select name="person">
    <option value="0">0 person</option>
    <option value="1">1 person</option>
    <option value="2">2 persons</option>
    <option value="3">3 persons</option>
    <option value="4">4 persons</option>
    <option value="5">5 persons</option>
  </select>
  <select name="age_p1">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <select name="age_p2">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="personandage" value="[X,X,X]" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So if I have e.g. 3 persons, 3 new select field appears to insert the age of each person.

> An example:
>   person 1 = 1 years; person 2 = 4 years; person 3 = 5 years

After submitting the form GET value have to be in an array like this **personandage=[1,4,5]**

Does someone has an idea how to realize this with PHP? Thank you!

Comment: This can be done easily with jquery, do you have to do it with PHP ?

Comment: Why not just look at `$_GET['person']` and `$_GET['age_p1']` etc etc

Comment: It is not really clear what you are actually trying to achieve from your question. Can you make it any clearer please

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Actually my aim is to find a way to echo the value inside the personandage parameter.

Comment: If I do it like this, each age of persons will be inside the value: `<input type="hidden" name="personandage" value="<?php echo '['.$_GET['age_p1'].','.$_GET['age_p2'].']'; ?>" >`, But if I have only one person with age of 4 years, the value only should be **[4]** and not **[4,0]**

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the html:

```
<form action="#">
  <select name="person">
    <option value="0">0 person</option>
    <option value="1">1 person</option>
    <option value="2">2 persons</option>
    <option value="3">3 persons</option>
    <option value="4">4 persons</option>
    <option value="5">5 persons</option>
  </select>
  <select name="age[]">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <select name="age[]">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="personandage" value="[X,X,X]" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and then you can `$_GET['age']` and should returns an array with the ages.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, by making the `age_p1`, `age_p2` .... into an array called lets say `ages[]` This way it does not matter to the PHP how many are used in the HTML or whether you add them dynamically with javascript.

```
<?php
    $pna = '[';
    if ( isset($_GET['submit'] ) {
        $pna = $_GET['person'];

        foreach ( $_GET['ages'] as $age ) {
            $pna .= ",$age";
        }
    }

    $pna .= ']';
?>

<form action="#">
  <select name="person">
    <option value="0">0 person</option>
    <option value="1">1 person</option>
    <option value="2">2 persons</option>
    <option value="3">3 persons</option>
    <option value="4">4 persons</option>
    <option value="5">5 persons</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ages[]">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ages[]">
    <option value="0">0 year</option>
    <option value="1">1 years</option>
    <option value="2">2 years</option>
    <option value="3">3 years</option>
    <option value="4">4 years</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="personandage" value="<?php echo $pna;?>" >
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
    <!--               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <!-- note I added an name attribute -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, put square brackets after the select. So

```
<select name="age[]">
...options...
</select>
<select name="age[]">
...options...
</select>
```

Would then be refered to as

```
_$GET["age"][0]
```

And

```
_$GET["age"][1]
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, noticed you wanted the array as personandage.

One option is to set the array on the page that your form redirects you to:

```
 $array_index = $_GET["person"] - 1
for ($i = 0, $i <= $array_index, $i++) {
    ${"personandage" . $i = array("p1", _$GET["age"][$i]);
}
```

Now your arrays should look like this

```
$personandage1
$personandage2
```

Etc...

Hope I understood your question :)
//written from My cellphone, havent tested the code.